# How to optimize a Sybase ASE database?

Tags: sap-ase, database-optimization

What are the tricks to optimize a sybase database?

What are the does and don'ts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems rather broad and open-ended.

For performance tuning guidelines across the entire product, I would probably start with the [several performance tuning books](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20020.1570/html/basics/title.htm) that are in the online documentation.

Ongoing performance optimization can often include monitoring by 3rd party products such as Confio's Ignite (I don't work for them, but it is impressive software).